# Unsupported locale setting while deploying on pythonanywhere

Tags: django, deployment, pythonanywhere

So I just got my website running on pythonanywhere but I get this error:

unsupported locale setting

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'esp_esp')

full traceback: http://dpaste.com/355VD3W

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your locale name is wrong for the platform of pythonanywhere which we can assume is Linux, not Windows, so it's not `esp_esp` (Windows)

but rather

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES.utf8')
```

or

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'es_ES')
```